# update multiple values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I am new to python and I am watching a lot of youtube videos to learn. I know how to update dictionary values individually. I want to update them all at once.

Example:

```
students = {'Eric': 15, 'Bob': 13, 'Chris': 16, 'Min': 25}
```

I want to update this to

```
{'Eric': 16, 'Bob': 14, 'Chris': 17, 'Min': 26}.
```

Each person's age increased by 1.

Comment: this is really trivial. Try a few things out. You will get it on your own. I would recreate the dictionary with a dict-comprehension

Comment: Look at [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Comment: @Ev. Kounis thanks for advise going though dict-comprehension videos now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
students = {key: students[key]+1 for key in students}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the dict.keys() functionality. Just tested, it works in Python 2 and 3.

```
students = {'Eric': 15, 'Bob': 13, 'Chris': 16, 'Min': 25}
for key in students.keys():
    students[key] += 1
print(students)
```

Comment: This does create a *new* `dictionary` though, not change the original

Comment: You don't need `students.keys()` to iterate over a `dict` - that's already the defaut, so all you need is `for key in students: ....`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: You are right, it is unnecessary. I was hoping that this way it is more clear to a programmer who is new to python.

Answer (score 2):

Single liner with `dictionary comprehension`:

```
{key:val+1 for key,val in students.items()}
```

#driver values:

```
IN : students = {'Eric': 15, 'Bob': 13, 'Chris': 16, 'Min': 25}
OUT : {'Eric': 16, 'Bob': 14, 'Chris': 17, 'Min': 26}
```

Comment: This does create a *new* `dictionary` though, not change the original

Comment: After that its a simple matter of assigning the newly generated `dict` to the old one, or you can use `update()`. The heavy work is done.

Comment: I know, but in terms of memory, creating a new dictionary isn't as efficient as modifying the original... Nevertheless, in this case, I would go for this solution as it is more compact so +1 **:)**

Comment: I would agree about the memory, but I prefer creating a new dictionary over modifying the old one, especially when iterating over it. Safer and faster code.

Comment: "After that its a simple matter of assigning the newly generated dict to the old one" => beware that if some other name references `students`, rebinding it won't affect other names, so if you really want to _update_ the dict you indeed need to use `studends.update({k:v+1 for k, v in students.items()})`

Answer (score 0):

You can call function keys() to do what you try to do.

```
for key in dict.keys():
  dict[key] += 1
```

Comment: `.keys()` is the default. You can loop through the keys by just typing `for key in dict:`. `dict` is a bad variable name btw. It overrides the Python keyword.